adding 2 new columns after text split
df<-c("Abc1038")

df<-strsplit(df, "(?=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])|(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])", perl=TRUE)

[[1]]
[1] "Abc"  "1038"

From here, I would like to separate one column to 2; say one is named "text" and another is named "num", may I know how should I go about it?
Below is an update reproducible example, thanks everyone.
column_one<-c("1234 AB 12/30/24 A23 One","4567 CD 05/30/24 B29 TWO")
column_two<-c("1","2")
df<-data.frame(col_one,col_two)
print(df)

                  col_one col_two
1 1234 AB 12/30/24 A23 One       1
2 4567 CD 05/30/24 B29 TWO       2

df<-separate(df,col_one,c("Number","Text","Expiration","Product","Type"),sep=" ")
df<-df[order(df$Expiration),] #separate the string in col_one and sort by date (expiration column)

df$N1<-strsplit(df$Product, "(?=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])|(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])", perl=TRUE)
df$N1<-do.call(rbind, df$N1)|>
  data.frame()|>
  rename(text = X1, num = X2)

print(df)

 Number Text Expiration Product Type col_two N1.text N1.num
2   4567   CD   05/30/24     B29  TWO       2       B     29
1   1234   AB   12/30/24     A23  One       1       A     23


Since your regex searches for text/number or number/text, I assume your real example might have both Abc1038 and 1038Abc data that needs to be split into the text and num columns?

Based on your output, you can easily get a data.frame:
df <- strsplit(df, "(?=[A-Za-z])(?<=[0-9])|(?=[0-9])(?<=[A-Za-z])", perl=TRUE)

library(dplyr)
do.call(rbind, df)|>
  data.frame()|>
  rename(text = X1, num = X2)
  text  num
1  Abc 1038


Try
as.data.frame(
    t(
        setNames(
            strsplit(df, "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", perl = TRUE)[[1]],
            c("text", "num")
        )
    )
)

which gives
  text  num
1  Abc 1038

